# Facebook workplace API in Python

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, facebook-workplace

This is the function that I use for making a call to Workplace API. But I don't see the page_id in the workplace (as opposed to in other Facebook pages).

Has anyone come across the same issue? Any suggestions would be appreciated !!

```
  def testFacebookPageData(page_id, access_token):
     base = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4"
     node = "/" + page_id
     parameters = "/?access_token=%s" % access_token
     url = base + node + parameters
     req = urllib2.Request(url)
     response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
     data = json.loads(response.read())
     print json.dumps(data, indent=4, sort_keys=True)

 testFacebookPageData(page_id, access_token)              //Function call
```

Comment: @Raaz: I saw a question from you regarding facebook graph api. Just wondering whether how you solved this problem?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to get a Workplace custom integration page ID (all badly documented by Facebook).  The easiest one is to access your bot page: just search your custom integration name in Workplace search bar (you would be able to find it as if it were a regular user).

Your bot page URL should look like:

- `https://<your_community>.facebook.com/<custom_integration_name>-<page_id>/`

The page ID is the last number of the URL (it is a 15-digit number).

Alternatively, you can also access this Facebook page:

- https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/

And paste your custom integration access token to see some relevant information of your access token, like permissions, but also the Page ID.  It is designed for Facebook, but it works for Workplace as well, since they both share basically the same API.